# How to create a struct based on the following json code to parse it successfully?

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and am encountering problems in parsing a local json file. Every time I try to decode the file, the following error pops up.

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "users", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"users\", intValue: nil) (\"users\").", underlyingError: nil)).

How should I structure my struct in order to parse the data?

```
{
    "Users": [{

        "name": "John",
        "username": "john1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {

        "name": "Smith",
        "username": "Sm2",
        "id": 2
    },
    {

        "name": "Nishanta",
        "username": "nisacharya",
        "id": 3
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your Users struct is not equal with service response.

Comment: the code above is the json file....I need help creating a struct

Comment: What is your struct? Write your struct

Comment: the above shown is the json file....I need to create a struct...

Comment: You can use [this link](https://quicktype.io/) to get a struct from your json

Comment: struct Usermodel: Codable{
        let name: String
        let username: String
        let id: Int
        

        
        init(name: String, username: String, id: Int) {
           self.name = name
            self.username = username
            self.id = id
   }

Comment: `users` != `Users`. Look at the part "Choose Properties to Encode and Decode Using Coding Keys" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error there is a typo, `Users` is uppercased and must be converted with a `CodingKey`

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let users : [User]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case users = "Users"
    }
}

struct User : Decodable {
    let name: String
    let username: String
    let id: Int 
}
```

And decode

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
let users = result.users
```

Comment: btw, how do I print out the individual names, usernames and id??

Comment: [task_5p.User(name: "John", username: "john1", id: 1), task_5p.User(name: "Smith", username: "Sm2", id: 2), task_5p.User(name: "Nishanta", username: "nisacharya", id: 3)]...This is the output. But I need to print out the individual values like name : John....username : john1....id:1...and so on

Comment: `for user in users { print(user.name, user.id) }`